# Should I store reference table vales as an enum?

Tags: c#, mysql, enums

Lets say I have two tables, one that stores cars with a foreign key to a second reference table that stores brands. What is better practice... to create an enum and make the car property the enum type, or to load a list of brand objects from the table?

At first glance I thought it would be better to have the brands load from the table because it wouldn't require code changes (to the enum) if new brands were added. But from a performance perspective, I would have to call the database every time I needed to find out all possible brands (e.g. in validation), and this could be expensive.

Whats a good practice?

```
`Car {
int SerialNumber;
(int or enum?) BrandId;
string Owner;
DateTime Year;
}`

`(class or enum?) Brand {
int Id;
string Name;
}`
```

Comment: Are you using any ORM, like EntityFramework?

Comment: Calculate costs of "reinstalling" software when you need to add new brand vs few more sql server trips.

Comment: Do you really have performance issues with implementation where you make database query for validating brands? What is purpose of database then, if you want keep data hard-coded in your source code? Use database and only if you have performance issues(I doubt about) you start consider another approach

Comment: @botond.botos I write my own sql queries, but may be switching to an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stay away from enum in MySQL; adding a new value to an enum field requires an ALTER TABLE that requires a sometimes costly reconstruction of the entire table.

Also, consider if you actually want brand to be an enum in your code. Do you really want to have to recompile and redeploy every time there is a new brand?

Even if you do decide that "recompile and redeploy" the right answer for you, there is nothing preventing you from just having the application itself (or it's installer/setup) ensure the brand lookup table corresponds to the enum that is in your code (*just make sure to specify the enum values' values explicitly, and not have the lookup table's id be an auto, to prevent mismatches*).

*One final thing to consider against an enum: If you have multiple **different** clients, you would need to keep the enum synchronized across all clients' code base.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have business logic that is different for different brands it might be better to put it in the code. To make sure that the id for a specific brand is equal in all databases. In that case check out refactorings like "replace type code with subclasses". If you dont use the id in your code to change some logic you can put the brands in the database. You can cache the values for better performance. I guess brands does not change that often.